# Cheese starts and takes picture, but freezes if I try to do anything else (take another picture or record a video)

Tags: video, webcam

Cheese starts and takes picture, but freezes if I try to do anything else (take another picture or record a video).  BIOS is the latest for this Desktop PC.  I waited 30 minutes and Cheese still frozen. Motherboard is ASUS TUF Z390-Plus Gaming (WI-FI). BIOS version is 3006.

Comment: try clear cheese cache im .cache dir

Answer (score 0):

BOINC was set to use CPU 100% of time.  I set BOINC to suspend calculations when keyboard or mouse was in use. Cheese seems to be working without problems now.